# HTTP Authentication - WWW-Authenticate header - multiple realms

Tags: http-authentication

Does anyone have any experience of supporting multiple realms in HTTP Authentication?

The Microsoft website states:

> Each authenticate response header
>   contains an available authentication
>   scheme and a realm. If multiple
>   authentication schemes are supported,
>   the server returns multiple
>   authenticate response headers. The
>   realm value is case-sensitive and
>   defines a protection space on the
>   proxy or server. For example, the
>   header "WWW-Authenticate: Basic
>   Realm="example"" would be an example
>   of a header returned when server
>   authentication is required.

This suggests that different areas of a website can be secured using different authentication methods. What we are confused about is how to determine what realm should be stated in the server response to a client request.

Does anyone have any examples of how multiple realms work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.47) allows for multiple `WWW-Authenticate` challenges to be present in a response, either within the same `WWW-Authenticate` header or using multiple `WWW-Authenticate` headers within the same response.

There are problems associated with this, as described in [RFC 2617, section 4.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-4.6). In theory, the client must choose the strongest authentication mechanism available, however, defining which one is the strongest is not always obvious.

I've never tried with multiple realms (and the same scheme, for example Basic), but I'm not aware of anything disallowing it. The main problem with multiple realms and the same scheme is that the browser is likely to be confused in terms of user-interface, in particular which realm it challenges the user with.

Comment: Regarding multiple WWW-Authenticate challenges, is there a consensus on whether use multiple WWW-Authenticate headers or to have multiple challenges within the same WWW-Authenticate header?

Comment: According to the specification, it's supposed to be equivalent, so conforming user-agents should support both. Whether they do it in practice, I'm not sure.

Comment: For completeness - a link to some tests in different browsers: http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc/httpauth/

Answer (score 5):

I have one good example using multiple authenticate headers when using a sharepoint site. 
The Sharepoint offer both Negotiate and NTLM when connecting first.

Firefox chooses NTLM but Chrome chooses Negotiate.

It is also a consequence that Chrome will always send the Authorization header along with the other requests but Firefox only at the beginning because of the NTLM challange-response protocol. See here more explanation http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html