# How does the System.Net.Http.HttpClient select authentication type?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Let's say I new up the `HttpClient` and send off a request to a protected endpoint like this:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "url");
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

I then get a response with the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Basic
Date ...
```

From the response headers, I see that I have three different options to authenticate with the server (Negotiate, NTLM, Basic). I then update my code to this:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential
    {
        UserName = "username",
        Password = "password"
    }
};
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "url");
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

I execute my program again, and this time I get a 200 OK in return. All fine.

If I inspect the request with fiddler, I see that the `HttpClient` decided to use "Negotiate" as the authentication method.

**Now, my question is:** how does the `HttpClient` decide which authentication type to apply? Does it have a precedence for some authentication types over others?

The docs on [`NetworkCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential?view=netframework-4.8) states that:

> The NetworkCredential class is a base class that supplies credentials
>   in password-based authentication schemes such as basic, digest, NTLM,
>   and Kerberos.

... so I know the credentials I provide could have been applied for all three authentication types, but I have not been able to figure out how / why it selects a specific authentication type over another.

Any insight into this is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: It's sequentially ordered in the response. Negotiate was first and negotiate is something the system could handle, so it went ahead and tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **GetCredential** method, it will give you the credential with the authentication type. A bit weird but works:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential
    {
        UserName = "username",
        Password = "password"       
    }.GetCredential("*", 80, "Basic") // Substitute * and 80 with url and port if possible
};
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "url");
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

#### After Comment clarification

When you have multiple Authentication Types, the client must use the strongest method available (but sometimes this is dificult to say).

**Source:** [HTTP Authentication - WWW-Authenticate header - multiple realms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576197/http-authentication-www-authenticate-header-multiple-realms/15894841)

Comment: Hi Oscar, thanks for taking time to look at this question. I'm not sure that your answer covers how the `HttpClient` selects which authentication type to use when multiple options are available. But thanks again for contributing! :)

Comment: Oh I see, I thoutght that you were trying to choose the type of authentication ```GetCredential("*", 80, "Basic")```